# floyd steinberg dithering algorithm implementation in opencv does not work properly

Tags: c++, ios, algorithm, opencv

I am using a piece of code that i got from `stackoverflow` for floyd steinberg dithering algorithm.

It is as follows.But it is not properly dithering the image as expected.Does anybody have a correct implementation of this or can anybody correct the following code. The actual requirement is to convert a `24 bit` color image into `1 bit` gray dithered image.

i think the floyd steinberg method part below is correct,but before that method is called some functions are called that i dont know.I am very new to opencv.it is for an ios project.

```
 -(UIImage*)processImage:(UIImage*)chosenImage//ios
    {


    int nrColors = 8;
        cv::Mat img;
        UIImageToMat(chosenImage, img);



// i am not sure of this part--->

        cv::Mat colVec = img.reshape(1, img.rows*img.cols); // change to a Nx3 column vector

        cv::Mat colVecD;
        colVec.convertTo(colVecD, CV_32FC3, 1.0); // convert to floating point

        cv::Mat labels, centers;
        cv::kmeans(colVecD, nrColors, labels,
                   cv::TermCriteria(CV_TERMCRIT_ITER, 100, 0.1),
                   3, cv::KMEANS_PP_CENTERS, centers); // compute k mean centers

        // replace pixels by there corresponding image centers


        cv::Mat imgPosterized = img.clone();
        for(int i = 0; i < img.rows; i++ )
        {
        for(int j = 0; j < img.cols; j++ )
        {
        for(int k = 0; k < 3; k++)
        {
        imgPosterized.at<cv::Vec3b>(i,j)[k] = centers.at<float>(labels.at<int>(j+img.cols*i),k);
        }
        }
        }



//<---- i am not sure of this part

        // convert palette back to uchar
        cv::Mat palette;
       centers.convertTo(palette,CV_8UC3,1.0);



        img= floydSteinberg(img,palette);


        cv::Mat imgGray;
        //cvtColor(img, imgGray,cv::COLOR_RGBA2GRAY);
        chosenImage= MatToUIImage(img);

    return chosenImage;   
    }

    //floyd steinberg algorithm
    cv::Mat floydSteinberg(cv::Mat imgOrig, cv::Mat palette)
    {
        cv::Mat img = imgOrig.clone();
        cv::Mat resImg = img.clone();
        for(int i = 0; i < img.rows; i++ )
        {
        for(int j = 0; j < img.cols; j++ )
        {
            cv::Vec3b newpixel = findClosestPaletteColor(img.at<cv::Vec3b>(i,j), palette);
            resImg.at<cv::Vec3b>(i,j) = newpixel;

            for(int k=0;k<3;k++)
            {
                int quant_error = (int)img.at<cv::Vec3b>(i,j)[k] - newpixel[k];
                if(i+1<img.rows)
                img.at<cv::Vec3b>(i+1,j)[k] = fmin(255,fmax(0,(int)img.at<cv::Vec3b>(i+1,j)[k] + (7 * quant_error) / 16));
                if(i-1 > 0 && j+1 < img.cols)
                img.at<cv::Vec3b>(i-1,j+1)[k] = fmin(255,fmax(0,(int)img.at<cv::Vec3b>(i-1,j+1)[k] + (3 * quant_error) / 16));
                if(j+1 < img.cols)
                img.at<cv::Vec3b>(i,j+1)[k] = fmin(255,fmax(0,(int)img.at<cv::Vec3b>(i,j+1)[k] + (5 * quant_error) / 16));
                if(i+1 < img.rows && j+1 < img.cols)
                img.at<cv::Vec3b>(i+1,j+1)[k] = fmin(255,fmax(0,(int)img.at<cv::Vec3b>(i+1,j+1)[k] + (1 * quant_error) / 16));
            }
        }
        }
        return resImg;
    }

    float vec3bDist(cv::Vec3b a, cv::Vec3b b)
    {
        return sqrt( pow((float)a[0]-b[0],2) + pow((float)a[1]-b[1],2) + pow((float)a[2]-b[2],2) );
    }

    cv::Vec3b findClosestPaletteColor(cv::Vec3b color, cv::Mat palette)
    {
        int i=0;
        int minI = 0;
        cv::Vec3b diff = color - palette.at<cv::Vec3b>(0);
        float minDistance = vec3bDist(color, palette.at<cv::Vec3b>(0));
        for (int i=0;i<palette.rows;i++)
        {
            float distance = vec3bDist(color, palette.at<cv::Vec3b>(i));
            if (distance < minDistance)
            {
                minDistance = distance;
                minI = i;
            }
        }
        return palette.at<cv::Vec3b>(minI);
    }
```

[image]

Comment: the problem is the `palette` which is 8bit at the moment. so your algorithm just converts it from 24bit to 8bit

Comment: This code isn't meant to dither to black & white but to an optimized color palette. And it is horribly inefficient.

Comment: @YvesDaoust i have added the cvtColor to convert the optimized color palette to grayscale.Do you have an implementation that converts a 24 bit color image to gray with floyd steinberg algorithm?

Comment: @bro not only that as u can see in the image, its not a properly dithered image.it should contain dots and not lines . and its partially converted only as u can see in the image the right side is not converted

Comment: Work with (R+G+B)/3 for the luminance, instead of 3 separate channels. Compare this average to 128 to decide black (0) or white (255). Use this value to compute the quantization error. Assign the destination image (0, 0, 0)/(255, 255, 255) or 0/255 or 0/1 depending on the pixel format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The offsets you are using when dithering are wrong. For example, you are changing the pixel at i-1, which is the previous row that you have already processed. Basically, you have the x and the y swapped.

Change the code to this:

```
for(int k=0;k<3;k++)
{
   int quant_error = (int)img.at<cv::Vec3b>(i,j)[k] - newpixel[k];
   if(j+1<img.cols)
       img.at<cv::Vec3b>(i,j+1)[k] = fmin(255,fmax(0,(int)img.at<cv::Vec3b>(i,j+1)[k] + (7 * quant_error) / 16));
   if(i+1 < img.rows && j-1 >= 0)
       img.at<cv::Vec3b>(i+1,j-1)[k] = fmin(255,fmax(0,(int)img.at<cv::Vec3b>(i+1,j-1)[k] + (3 * quant_error) / 16));
   if(i+1 < img.rows)
        img.at<cv::Vec3b>(i+1,j)[k] = fmin(255,fmax(0,(int)img.at<cv::Vec3b>(i+1,j)[k] + (5 * quant_error) / 16));
   if(i+1 < img.rows && j+1 < img.cols)
        img.at<cv::Vec3b>(i+1,j+1)[k] = fmin(255,fmax(0,(int)img.at<cv::Vec3b>(i+1,j+1)[k] + (1 * quant_error) / 16));
}
```

The reason only 3/4 of the image is being dithered is because the image passed in has 4 channels and you are processing it as if it has 3. You can fix this by using `img.at<cv::Vec4b>` instead of `img.at<cv::Vec3b>`.

If you want to modify the dithering you can use a different [error-diffusion kernel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_diffusion#Enter_the_digital_era). Floyd Steinberg uses the 7 3 5 1 pattern but you can use different patterns and kernel sizes to dither different amounts and with different characteristics. For example you can diffuse less than the total amount of error. Floyd Steinberg diffuses all the error because 7/16 + 3/16 + 5/16 + 1/16 = 1, but you can choose terms that add up to less than one. [Atkinson dithering](http://verlagmartinkoch.at/software/dither/index.html) (the kind used on Apple Macintoshes) for example only diffuses 6/8ths of the error, which gives it a slightly more high contrast look. Different kernels will have slightly different speckling patterns and "looks". If you just want to have a single control for "dither amount" just have a value between 0 and 1 and multiply each of the terms of your kernel by it. A simple way to do implement this in your code would be to multiply the 7 3 5 1 by a value between 0 and 256 representing your dither amount, and divide by 4096 instead of 16.

Comment: it is giving the same output when compared to the previous code.can you please check why this image is converted partially only

Comment: It is completely identical to previously or just similar?

Comment: ok i think its a bit better now,the lines are less visible now...however the right part remains unconverted.. can you check that

Comment: It's converting 3/4 of the image by the looks of it. Perhaps the image passed in has 4 channels but you are treating it as 3 channel? Try using img.at<cv::Vec4b>

Comment: ok that fixed the issue.now the image looks fine..can you put it as the answer.do you know how to increase or decrease the amount of dithering of the image.